# Python Flask Wtforms File Field full path

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

When you make a file field with WTForms in Flask, it only returns the filename. Does anyone know how to get it to return the full path of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The file was uploaded from the user, the browser gets it and keeps it on the sky, so you can save it with a path. That's why you can't get its full path.

If an apple flies in the sky, how do you know which apple tree he comes from?

Comment: Thanks makes sense.